# Roots of a projective polynomial

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, galois-extensions

Relation between  the number of roots of a linearized polynomial and projective polynomial.

If we have a linearized polynomial of $\sigma$-degree $2$ over $F_{q^n}$ where $\sigma=q^s$, we can factor out $x$ as follows:

$$l(x)=x^{\sigma^2}+ax^{\sigma}+bx=x(x^{\sigma^2-1}+ax^{\sigma-1}+b)=xl_1(x)$$.

then if $l(x)=0$, $x\neq 0$ and  $y=x^{\sigma-1}$ we get

$$y^{\sigma+1}+ay+b=0$$

It is clear that $x=0$ is always a root for $l(x)=0$.

**Question:**

What is the relation between the number of roots of $l_1(x)=0$ over $F_{q^n}$ and the  roots of the projective polynomial equation $p(y)=y^{\sigma+1}+ay+b=0$?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews, i updated my question.

Comment: Here when assuming $x \ne 0$ you are looking at the number of roots in $k^*$. If $0$ is not a root of the polynomial then it has the same number of roots in $k$ and $k^*$. Given a polynomial $f(x)$ and its homogeneization $F(x,y)$ then $f,F$ have the same number of roots (in $k$ and $\Bbb{P}^1(k) = k \cup \infty$)

Comment: Sorry about missing this question earlier. Presumably the coefficients $a,b$ are from $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$? Do we know anything about the relation of $s$ and $n$? Anyway, the zeros of $\ell(x)$ in an algebraic closure form a 2-dimensional subspace $V$ over the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^s}$. The zeros in $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ are thus the intersection $V\cap \Bbb{F}_{q^n}$, which is a 2-dimensional space over $\Bbb{F}_{q^m}$, $m=\gcd(n,s)$. Probably something can be said about the relation to zeros $p(y)$ as well. Again $m$ will play a role.

Comment: thanks for your reply, $gcd(s,n)=1$ and coefficients are chosen from $F_{q^n}$.